# Adjectiv from partizip declination

Tags: adjective, standard-german, past-participle

I've encountered this sentence as an example on wiktionary:

> In den letzten Tagen hat es wieder vermehrt Anschläge im Irak gegeben.

As far as I know `vermehrt` is a partizip 2 form of `vermehren` which is acting as a verb here. But how is it declined here? Shouldn't it be `vermehrte` according to strong declination of adjectives (without article)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In den letzten Tagen hat es wieder vermehrt Anschläge im Irak gegeben.

In that sentence, the *Partizip II* is not declined because it is used as an adverb. It describes the predicate *hat gegeben*.

> In den letzten Tagen hat es wieder vermehrt**e** Anschläge im Irak gegeben.

Here the *Partizip II* is declined and becomes an attribute to *Anschläge*. The meaning is pretty much the same because there is no other valid interpretation in this case.

---

However, in simpler cases it often makes a big difference:

> Sie isst **vermehrt** Obst.

*She eats fruit **more often**.*

> Sie isst **vermehrtes** Obst.

*She eats **propagated** fruit.*

That's because the verb *vermehren* (as many other verbs) has multiple meanings which shine through.